# Why isn't my rx subscription triggered on my onNext?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, publishsubject

Playing around with `Rx Swift` I have run into a situation where my `subscription` doesn't trigger.

I have two `viewControllers`. The first has a `label` that the `subscriber` should update, like this:

```
func listen() {
   print("In func")
   let sec = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondvc") as! SecondViewController

   sec.myRx.subscribe(onNext: {
    print("SUBSCRIBED", $0)
       self.rxLabel.text = $0
   })
}
```

If you go to the sencond `viewController` there is a button that sets off an `onNext` event. Like this:

```
    var myRx = PublishSubject<String>()

    @IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
        myRx.asObserver().onNext("Hello")
    }
```

So, in my head, when `myButton` is pressed in the second `viewController` the `label` in the first `viewController` should update when going back to that `viewController`. But from what I can tell, the function is triggered, but the `subscription` isn't triggered at all.

Comment: Are you certain that you are presenting the same view controller that you are instantiating? I ask because that part is not in the snippet.

Comment: @nanibir You were right. I changed it, but it still didn't effect the outcome. Thanks for noticing though. Edited answer.

Comment: @nanibir Ok, solved it now. You were right. It was an issue with not using the same instance on the subscriber as the one used to present the second vc. I made a new instannce and subscribed to that. Thanks for the help. If you want me to upvote and check answer, write a proper response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you are subscribing to the same `PublishSubject` you're posting events to. Easiest way to confirm this is to by setting breakpoints and checking the address.